# Asterisk - Any way to end/cancel the queue wrap-up time?

Tags: asterisk

Any way to end the queue wrap-up time?
We define a wrap-up time of 60 seconds to allow the agents to finish their notes from a call.  In some cases, the full 60 seconds is not needed and our agents would like to end their wrap-up time.

Note:I dont want use pause/unpause commands, because I am tracking the pause/unpause events to  track the breaks (metting, launch, break, etc) times.

Comment: Please add more details and code snippets to describe your problem in a clearer fashion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there are no way change wrapuptime dynamicaly.

But posible create dialplan/web page support which will pause/unpause or just not allow call device while puting notes.

You also can mark pauses created by web page, so not use it for track breaks.

Answer (score 0):

Bit ancient question, but there is actually a tool which allows you to manage wrap up/pause/unpause of agents and gives you many more features to control/monitor your call center so it might be worth looking at. Have a look at OrderlyStatsSE.